# Example of using multiple then in test Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

While learning android testing have figured out that I can use 'then' several times. But don't understand cases where it might be helpful. For example

```
when(mockObject.add(any()))
.thenReturn(true,false)
.thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually defines what happens on consecutive calls.  The first time returns, the next time throws.  I'm not a fan of this behavior (I think its cleaner to specify changes in returns specifically and as close to the call as possible) but there's times with calls deep in the stack its unavoidable.

So basically `when(...).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false)` will return true the first time and false after that.  This is the same as `when(...).thenReturn(true, false)`

Comment: But why he is throwing exception after getting result?

Comment: How should I know? It depends on what he's testing. Maybe he's emulating a stream of data and there's only 2 elements. There's hundreds of reasons why that may be the correct behavior

Comment: I just trying to understand the flow. After adding any data on first step how he can retrieve three different results? true / false / exception? The result of method is one. Or it is an exception but exception is not going THEN it is going as first result. Right?

Comment: It's done in order. The first time it's called, it returns true. The second, false. The third, it throws an exception

Comment: Ok so please confirm that I understand right that it making 3 iteration with when and checking 3 scenarios separate from each other? like this when->than true/ when -> than false / when -> than exception?

Comment: Yes.  The first time add() is called will return true.  The second time false.  The third time will throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you for clarification